# TypeError: con.connect is not a function con.connect(function(err) {

Tags: mysql, node.js

Why am I getting the following error when I try to use 'con' on the second file?:

```
TypeError: con.connect is not a function     con.connect(function(err) {
```

File - connections.js:

```
const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host:'127.0.0.1', // host of server
  user:'root', // MySQL user
  password:'', // MySQL password
  database: "rpg"
});
exports.con = con
```

File - events.js:

```
const con = require('./connection');
mp.events.add('playerJoin', (player) => {
    var socialID = player.rgscId
    con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('The following error happened while connecting to [[rpg]]: ' + err);  
            throw err;
        }
    etc etc etc
```

Everytime I use con on the first file it works, but not on the second one, unless I repeat the whole mysql.createConnection.

My index.js also has:

```
const con = require('./connection');
```

Comment: try exporting it with module.exports.con = con

Comment: You need to `const con = require('./connection').con;`

Comment: Thank you both! I went for Manuel's first and it worked.

Comment: Also, could you explain to me why it doesn't work without the .con?